# XGBoost on python : what is wrong with xgb.cv?

Tags: python, classification, cross-validation, xgboost

I'm trying to use xgboost on python. Here is my code. `xgb.train` works but I get an error with `xgb.cv`, although it seems I used it the correct way.

The following works for me:

```
###### XGBOOST ######

import datetime
startTime = datetime.datetime.now() 

import xgboost as xgb
data_train   = np.array(traindata.drop('Category',axis=1))
labels_train = np.array(traindata['Category'].cat.codes)

data_valid   = np.array(validdata.drop('Category',axis=1))
labels_valid = np.array(validdata['Category'].astype('category').cat.codes)

weights_train = np.ones(len(labels_train))
weights_valid  = np.ones(len(labels_valid ))

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( data_train, label=labels_train,weight = weights_train)
dvalid  = xgb.DMatrix( data_valid , label=labels_valid ,weight = weights_valid )




param = {'bst:max_depth':5, 'bst:eta':0.05, # eta [default=0.3]
         #'min_child_weight':1,'gamma':0,'subsample':1,'colsample_bytree':1,'scale_pos_weight':0, # default
         # max_delta_step:0 # default
         'min_child_weight':5,'scale_pos_weight':0, 'max_delta_step':2,
         'subsample':0.8,'colsample_bytree':0.8,
         'silent':1, 'objective':'multi:softprob' }


param['nthread'] = 4
param['eval_metric'] = 'mlogloss'
param['lambda'] = 2
param['num_class']=39

evallist  = [(dtrain,'train'),(dvalid,'eval')] # if there is a validation set
# evallist  = [(dtrain,'train')]                   # if there is no validation set

plst = param.items()
plst += [('ams@0','eval_metric')]

num_round = 100

bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5 ) # early_stopping_rounds=10 # when there is a validation set

# bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,nfold = 5,evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5)

bst.save_model('0001.model')

# dump model
bst.dump_model('dump.raw.txt')
# dump model with feature map
# bst.dump_model('dump.raw.txt','featmap.txt')

x = datetime.datetime.now() - startTime
print(x)
```

But if I change the line...

```
bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5 )
```

...to this one...

```
bst.res = xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,nfold = 5,evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

...I get the following unexpected error:

> File "", line 45
>       bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,nfold = 5,evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5) SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after
>   keyword arg

**EDIT1**: I tried changing the order of keywords as well:

```
bst.res = xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,evallist,nfold = 5,early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

...and I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-49-36177ef64bab> in <module>()
      43 # bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5 ) # early_stopping_rounds=10 # when   there is a validation set
      44 
 ---> 45 bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,evallist,nfold =5 ,early_stopping_rounds=5)
      46 
      47 bst.save_model('0001.model')

 TypeError: cv() got multiple values for keyword argument 'nfold'
```

**EDIT2**
After all, there is no need in CV for a validation set.
there is no argument `evals` in the signature of xgb.cv (although it is present for `xgb.train`)
so I removed it and change the line to:

```
bst.res=xgb.cv(params=plst,dtrain=dtrain,num_boost_round=num_round,nfold = 5,early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

then i get this error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.pyc
in cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, nfold, metrics, obj, feval,
maximize, early_stopping_rounds, fpreproc, as_pandas, show_progress,
show_stdv, seed)
    413     best_score_i = 0
    414     results = []
--> 415     cvfolds = mknfold(dtrain, nfold, params, seed, metrics, fpreproc)
    416     for i in range(num_boost_round):
    417         for fold in cvfolds:  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.pyc
in mknfold(dall, nfold, param, seed, evals, fpreproc)
    280         else:
    281             tparam = param
--> 282         plst = list(tparam.items()) + [('eval_metric', itm) for itm in evals]
    283         ret.append(CVPack(dtrain, dtest, plst))
    284     return ret
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?  It states very precisely what your problem is.

Comment: when i look at tutorials, it says you just need to specify the extra  nfold parameter and everything will be fine

Comment: The *error message* that you posted already answers the question.  `non-keyword arg after keyword arg`.  `arg` is short for `argument`.  If you don't know the difference between a keyword and a non-keyword argument, the python documentation is extremely helpful.

Comment: Its hard to straddle the line between cryptic, and giving enough information that the poster can help themselves out of a bind with a prod in the correct direction, so I apologize for that.  You did figure out what I was going for though, so I wasn't totally off.

Comment: Not sure what's up now though, that last call looks like it's good.

Comment: my understanding is that evallist is the list of sets for which evalmetric will be evaluated. the model is trained on dtrain (training set), but does compute the logloss eval metric on both dtrain and dvalid (validation set)

Comment: i should have started my post with the first call error. actually i got this error first thats why i changed the order of args

Comment: Think I figured it out.  Sorry again about being a bit terse.

Comment: @FaguiCurtain: ignore tutorials when they conflict with the package's actual code, as in this case. Many tutorials are bad, vague or get out-of-date quickly, also most of these packages have version changes, so what worked on previous versions can break.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the signature of `xgboost.cv`, copied from the documentation

```
xgboost.cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=10, nfold=3, stratified=False,
    folds=None, metrics=(), obj=None, feval=None, maximize=False,
    early_stopping_rounds=None, fpreproc=None, as_pandas=True,
    verbose_eval=None, show_stdv=True, seed=0, callbacks=None)
```

Notice that there are exactly *two* strictly positional parameters (`params, dtrain`), and the parameter in the fourth position is `nfold`.

Your call is:

```
xgb.cv(plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist, nfold=5, early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

When python parses a function call, it first matches all the arguments you passed positionally *by position*.  So in your case, python matches like this

```
Formal Parameter <-- What You Passed In
          params <-- plst
          dtrain <-- dtrain
 num_boost_round <-- num_round
           nfold <-- evallist
```

Then python matches all the arguments you passed in as keywords *by name*.  So in your case, python matches like this

```
Formal Parameter <-- What You Passed In
          nfold <-- 5
          early_stopping_rounds <-- 5
```

So you can see that the formal parameter `nfold` gets assigned twice, which is what is generating this

```
TypeError: cv() got multiple values for keyword argument 'nfold'
```

Probably the easiest and clearest fix is to pass *all* your arguments as keywords.  Generally it is a best practice to limit your positional arguments to a very small number, most programmers seem to aim for about two positional parameters, at most.

> but im getting another error, i can't figure it out alas

Looks like you're passing a list where a dictionary is expected.  Using the docs again, the first argument:

> params (dict) – Booster params.

Should be a dictionary.

Comment: thanks. python is a bit annoying to me. i'm more comfortable with F# where everything is typed and has a full signature. i have had a lot of troubles passing the wrong object as arg (like a pandas dataframe instead of a numpy array,... and more complicated examples)

Comment: Python just wants you to be really explicit, and when something is wrong it would rather set off alarms than silently do maybe the wrong thing.

Comment: Between you and me, even though I'm a huge python fan, I also prefer static typing.  Especially when supported by a strong functional type system.

Comment: i really thought your answer would help me solve this problem once and for all, but im getting another error, i can't figure it out alas